# Option + Z keystroke does not insert the ohm symbol/omega (Ω)

Tags: macos, shortcut, keybindings

Every article that I can find on web suggests the keystroke <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> to insert that `Ω` symbol on a Mac. However, on my Mac, when I press that combination, I get the `ˀ` character. I followed the instructions in [this](http://www.corpbuscards.com/mackeycodesfortyping.htm#math) article.

Comment: What is your configured keyboard layout?

Answer (score 3):

After changing my **Input Source** to `U.S.` (via System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources), the keystroke works as expected. Now pressing <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> inserts the `Ω` character.

Comment: What input source were you using before -- ABC Extended?

Comment: Correct, ABC Extended.